# In a repository pattern, how can I integrate domain object factories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, poco

I have a project structured like this :

WebSite --> Services --> Repositories --> Domain Objects

I use Entity Framework 6 and Autofac.

I've been told I should remove all construction logic from my domain objects so they remain as POCO as possible. The thing is, I have properties that should be initialized when a new object is created such as CreationDate and UserIdCreatedBy

As an example, if I have a Client object, I would use the following logic in the Client class constructor :

```
public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        this.CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal is CustomPrincipal
            && ((CustomPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal).CustomIdentity != null
            && ((CustomPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal).CustomIdentity.User != null)
        {
            this.UserIdCreatedBy = ((CustomPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal).CustomIdentity.User.UserId;
        }
    }

    ... Properties and such
}
```

So now, I would like to take this constructor logic out of the domain object into a factory for that object. How can I do it gracefully so that Entity Framework uses it when I call MyContext.Clients.Create()? Is that even possible? I know calling the Thread's CurrentPrincipal is not all that good either, but it's for the example to show the logic could be more complex than a plain default value.

Thanks a lot

Comment: So they want you to create an anemic model. Just a bag of data without behaviour ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck That's what POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) is in it's simplest form. ;)

Comment: that is an anti pattern.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. How would you do it?

Comment: question is why you want to remove that constructor logic. You have been told to remove it, by whom ? If that is your boss and you cannot change his mind, then you have to do it no matter what i say ;-) I am actually trying to achieve the opposite of what you do here. I am trying to put behavior in my domain objects.

Comment: Indeed, I was told by my lead programmer to remove at least the reference to the current thread and the "hard reference" to the CustomPrincipal type as it hinders testability (or so he says). I could put the code in my Service, which is responsible for business logic, but I feel it does not belong there. And my lead programmer insist on me finding the solution on my own because he thinks I will learn something from it. He may be right or he may be wrong, but that leaves me where I am now; posting in here to find the best possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use DB storage to store the items (not for manipulations with them) I think you could use separate class for instantiating objects. (Some kind of factory as you described.)

For example, in my apps I often have UserManager class. This class does all work relating to the users creation depending on the login method (email+password, social ID etc). Also this class might contain methods for changing password etc.

UPD:

I use data layer as something that knows how to create/update/read/delete objects from/to database. In addition, class that works with db can has methods like selectByThis, selectByThat etc. So you never need to write something db-specific somewhere in your code, except db layer. (I mean that you never need to write something like .Where(a => a.SomeProp == true), you just use special method for this, so if you change the db you will just have to change your db layer, now whole the project.)

So yes, when I need some special logic for initializing object I use separate class. (Like some kind of manager.) That class does all the work and then just tells the db layer: “hey, I did all the work, so just save this object for me!”

It simplifies the maintenance for you. Also, this is how to follow the rule of single responsibility. One class initialize, do some work and the other class saves.

Comment: I am indeed using DB Storage, Entity Framework to be more exact.

If I understand well what you are saying, I should write my creation logic in my repository, right? Because my repository is where the services get the objects from whether it's from scratch (new) or from the DB. Or should I create a new layer between Services and Repositories?

I want to be as clean and as efficient as possible to maximize maintainability and adhere to Robert C. Martin's "Clean code" principles.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, with that manager, how do you use it and where is it in the project? Do you have a "object manager" project between the domain and the data projects (or in parallel with the domain)? Does only the data layer know of the existence of those manager classes and all the other layers ask the data layer for the object even when creating a new one?